# I can't properly select an XML node in a SOAP header in C#.Net

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have an XML document wrapped in a SOAP header but I can't select a single node. I think I am just misunderstanding how to repsresent the tree when nodes are prepended with text.  e.g. wsu:Timestamp, wsu:Created

Here is the top part of my XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:itk="urn:nhs-itk:ns:201005">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>39c6f52b-1be0-42a9-a219-5d6ececd1695</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>urn:nhs-itk:services:201005:SendCDADocument-v2-0</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:To>http://127.0.0.1:4000/syncsoap</wsa:To>
        <wsa:From>
            <wsa:Address>http://localhost</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:From>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="D6CD5232-14CF-11DF-9423-1F9A910D4703">
                <wsu:Created>2015-01-30T19:40:00</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-01-30T19:50:00</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>TKS Server test</wsse:Username>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
```

Here is my code, which throws a null pointer exception on the Select Single Node because it doesn't return a match.

```
private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
    DateTime myCreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;


    soapEnvelop.Load(@“c:\myFile.xml");
    soapEnvelop.SelectSingleNode("/soap/Envelope/Header/wsse/Security/wsu/Timestamp/Created").InnerText = myCreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    return soapEnvelop;
}
```

I triple checked for case sensitivity and I don't see a mistake there.  And when I put a breakpoint in I can see the XML is loaded into the soapEnvelop object fine.

I implemented the suggestion of using a Namespace Manager and I could select several nodes fine. However, I have an issue with matching the Id value in wsu:Timestamp.  I tried the following but all couldn't match:

```
soapEnvelop.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp/Id", ns).InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
soapEnvelop.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp/wsu:Id", ns).InnerText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
soapEnvelop.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp", ns).Attributes["Id"].Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

I figured out my last problem.  If you have an attribute that is empty then the Value() call must "fail". I had modified my xml doc I was working with when I added in the code suggested below and took out the existing ID and replaced it with "", which is what I was doing with Created and Expires.  The issue must be you can have an InnerText for a node that is an empty string but you can't have that for an attribute. Maybe that is considered invalid XML so .Net says "no go dude".

What is odd is that when I changed my code to do this call before my initial setting of Id.

```
XmlNode myNode = soapEnvelop.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp", ns);
myNode.Attributes["wsu:Id"].Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

It set the value fine even if Id was "" in my xml file.  That is how I stumbled onto my solution because I left my original call still in the code and it didn't throw an exception so it got me thinking the only difference is Id has a value.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a namespace issue. The nodes that you are selecting don't all belong to the same namespace so effectively does not have access to them. You need to use an XmlNameSpaceManager to store your namespaces and specify which namespace each element belongs to.

Such as:

```
    private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
    {
        XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
        DateTime myCreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;


        soapEnvelop.Load(@"c:\myFile.xml");

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(soapEnvelop.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        ns.AddNamespace("wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
        ns.AddNamespace("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        ns.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

        soapEnvelop.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp/wsu:Created", ns).InnerText = myCreatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");

    }
```

There are more elegant ways of performing this task but this at least will allow you to proceed.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I knew it was because I didn't understand the tree worked.

Comment: I edited my main question with a follow on issue I hit after my initial node matching worked based on your suggestion.

Comment: You could use this for your XPath: `//soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsu:Timestamp/@wsu:Id`. Glad it worked Ok, please be so kind and mark as answer thanks :). Also, I recommend http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath for testing your XPath queries.